# JIRA Groovy Script - Check on duplicate sub-tasks

Tags: groovy, jira

The code below creates 3 sub-tasks for each Version selected in **SW Version** custom field. This is placed on a workflow transition as a post function and works perfectly. However, if the workflow transition is revisited it creates duplicate subtasks for the already selected versions.

Example: 
SW Version field has 5 options: 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5

if a user selected 1 and 2 and proceeds with the transition, it will create 6 subtasks 3 for each version selected. (All good here)

if the user updates the SW Version field to 1, 2 , 3, and 4 which already has 1 and 2 pre-selected, it will create 12 additional subtasks making the total 18 with 6 duplicates of 1 and 2.

I wanted to put a check on these duplicates, so basic logic is if the subtask already exist go to the next one. Something like for each version selected, check if subtasks already exist and proceed. I tried doing it various ways and failed. Have commented out some codes below to get summary of the subtasks and compare with all existing subtasks summary but it doesn't work.

In addition I tried doing this to no avail.

```
if(issue.getSubTaskObjects()*.summary.equals(summaryText)){
     log.info("Subtask already exists")
     return;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

```
 import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
    import com.atlassian.jira.util.ImportUtils
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.index.IssueIndexManager 
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.IssueLinkManager
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.index.IssueIndexingService
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger
    import org.apache.log4j.Level

    log.info("Processing: " + issue.key);

    CustomFieldManager customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.customFieldManager
    IssueManager issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager();

    def cfM119 = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("SW Version")


    log.info("cfM119: " + cfM119)

    def m119VersionArray = issue.getCustomFieldValue(cfM119) as String[]


    def reqAssignee = 'user1'
    def swAssignee = 'user2'
    def testAssignee = 'user3'

    //collecting subtask object

    //Collection allsubtasks = issue.getSubTaskObjects()
    //for(Issue allsubtask: allsubtasks) {
    //def subtaskSummary = allsubtask.getSummary() as String[]
    //log.info("Subtask Summary" + subtaskSummary)

    //if (subtaskSummary[]){
      //  log.info("Subtask already exists")}
    //else {


    m119VersionArray.each{ version ->
            createSubTask("", version, "_Approved_REQ", reqAssignee)
            createSubTask("", version, "_Approved_SW", swAssignee)
            createSubTask("", version, "_Approved_TEST", testAssignee)
            }

    def createSubTask(String component, version, type, String assignee) {  
    def Long issueLinkType = new Long (10702)
    def Long sequence = new Long (1)

    //Issue issue
    def summaryText = component + version + " " + type 
    def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.issueManager
    def issueFactory = ComponentAccessor.issueFactory
    def subTaskManager = ComponentAccessor.subTaskManager
    def issueLinkManager = ComponentAccessor.issueLinkManager
    def userManager = ComponentAccessor.userManager
    def authenticationContext = ComponentAccessor.jiraAuthenticationContext

     if(issue.getSubTaskObjects()*.summary.equals(summaryText)){
         log.info("Subtask already exists")
         return;
     }

    // Defining subtask

    def newIssue = issueFactory.getIssue()
    newIssue.setIssueTypeId("5")
    newIssue.setParentId(issue.getId())
    newIssue.setProjectObject(issue.getProjectObject())
    newIssue.setSummary(summaryText)
    newIssue.setAssignee(userManager.getUserByName(assignee))
    newIssue.setDescription(issue.getDescription())

    log.info("Creating subtask - " + summaryText)

    def subTask = issueManager.createIssueObject(authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser(), newIssue)
    subTaskManager.createSubTaskIssueLink(issue, subTask, authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser())
    issueLinkManager.createIssueLink(issue.getId(), newIssue.getId(), issueLinkType, sequence, authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser())


    // reindex
    ImportUtils.setIndexIssues(true)
    IssueIndexingService issueIndexService = 
    ComponentAccessor.getComponent(IssueIndexingService.class)
    issueIndexService.reIndex(subTask)
    ImportUtils.setIndexIssues(false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working just because `issue.getSubTaskObjects()*.summary` return array and then you try compare this array with string in `.equals(summaryText)`. But you was close and if change this part to `issue.getSubTaskObjects()*.summary.contains(summaryText)` (mean you search `summaryText` in each array element) it will be work pretty well.

Also in my opinion next code will be more understandable and clear `issue.getSubTaskObjects().find{it.getSummary() == summaryText}` (this also will be work inside `if` statement)